# jQuery not working (not having any effect) in any browser, but it works in Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery

This has been frustrating me for ages now. I've tried both downloading the jQuery as a local file, and also linking to it as a http.
The path is correct, there are no errors in the actual code because it works perfectly in **Codepen**. It is in the right place.
I have tried placing it both in the `<head>` tags, and also before the `</body>` tag, still no luck - nothing happens. Here it is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/javascript.js"></script>
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: '96%' }, 500);
    });
});
```

Is there any reason why this could be? Regular Javascript works fine, and when I tried doing a simple alert('hello'); it also works.
This is really frustrating, any suggestions welcome!

Here's the link to the Codepen: http://codepen.io/Pea92/pen/WvrXRY

Comment: Show your script in context in the html.

Comment: have you tried just `alert('test')` to see if it's the connection to jQuery or your code?

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing an alert('hello') which worked fine.

Comment: You need to use jquery 1.1.7  url it work some problem in jquery 2.1.1 but it doesn't means it not work i have did this.

Comment: Oh right, how do I get the url for this?

Comment: @psm93 Can you at least post the link to your codepen, and also show _all_ the relevant code/markup in your question?  There's nothing in your question to indicate why it may or may not be working.

Comment: I have post example code try this reply and you should try by remove your external .js (<script src="/js/javascript.js"></script> )

Comment: Cannot see why it's not working. As per @JamesThorpe said, please include **all** the relevant code for us to help debug.

Comment: What's in `javascript.js`? Anything that could be overwriting `$`? Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`, eg, `jQuery(document).ready...`

Comment: This could be an issue with `http` and `https`, have you checked the console log for errors? Hit `CTRL + SHIFT + J` to check console logs in Google Chrome.

Comment: @mk117 Unlikely - the external script is coming from `https`.  If the html page was on `https` and trying to get a script from `http`, I would agree with you.  It's a downgrade in security that can cause issues, not an upgrade. (But yes, checking for errors in the console is a good idea!)

Answer (score -2):

This code work for me you should try by remove external.js ()

```
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
   $("p").toggle();
  });
});



 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    var div = $("div");  
    div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
    div.animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow");
});
});

</script> 

 </head>
 <body>

 <br />


 <button>Click Here</button>

 <p>This is a example of jquery 2.1.1 to show and hide contain on view page                 </p>
 <p> below example for animation effect on dataweb view page with jquery 2.1.1 </p>

  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:200px;position:absolute;">Example</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I'll try it. But why wouldn't it work in an external file?

Comment: I might be working because the jquery from google has `https` while codepen and your website would be in `http`... is that correct?

Comment: Ya that issue is happened with me also